# align image in div with centered width, set height

Tags: css

i searched and searched, but it doesnt pop up. i have a sidebar fixed to stick to the left of the view port and fill the page top to bottom. so a sidebar. and i have a logo i want to put in the middle of the width, but i dont want it anchored to the top of the sidebar. when i tried to use position:fixed and top:100px, it moved way down the sidebar and anchored to the left of the screen. heres what i have:

```
#logo {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

theres not much code for me to give, its simple. i have this 
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iC8I.jpg)
and all i want is that logo to be further down. not vertically centered, just moved down, as if top: 200px; is applied

Comment: Include more _CSS_ **and** _HTML_ please!  `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work unless you supply a width.

Comment: Do you want the logo/image centered both horizontally and vertically within the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

The information you have suppled is a little vague, especially on code. So, here's my best guess at what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/tynmy/

*CSS*

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.left {
    background-color: green;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.right {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 66.66666%;
}
.left > img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}
```

*HTML*

```html
<div class="left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/" />
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```